# Match a piece of text from the beginning up to the first occurrence of multicharacter substring

Tags: python, regex

I want a regex search to end when it reaches ". ", but not when it reaches "."; I'm aware of using `[^...]` to exclude single characters, and have been using this to stop my search when it reaches a certain character. This does not work with strings though, as `[^. ]` stops when it reaches either character. Say I've got the code

```py
import re

def main():
    my_string = "The value of the float is 2.5. The int's value is 2.\n"
    re.search("[^.]*", my_string)

main()
```

Which gives a match object with the string

`"The value of the float is 2"`

How can I change this so that it only stops after the string ". "?

Bonus question, is there any way to tell regex to stop whenever it reaches one of multiple strings? Using the above code as an example, if I wanted the search to end when it found the string ". " or the string ".\n", how would I go about it? Thanks!

Comment: Use `r'^(.*?)\.\s'`. What you asked for is ``r'^(.*?)\.(?: |\n)'``

Comment: Try `[^.]*(?:\.+?[^ \n][^.]*)*?\.[ \n]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To match from the start of a string till the `.` followed with whitespace, use

```
^(.*?)\.\s
```

If you want to only require a space or newline after a dot, use either of (the second is best if you have single chars only, use alternation if there are multicharacter alternatives)

```
^(.*?)\.(?: |\n)
^(.*?)\.[ \n]
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/NawTpN/1).

**Details**

- `^` - start of a string
- `(.*?)` - Capturing group 1: any 0+ chars other than linebreak chars, as few as possible
- `\.` - a literal `.` char
- `\s` - a whitespace char
- `(?: |\n)` / `[ \n]` - a non-capturing group matching either a space or (`|`) a newline.

[Python demo](https://ideone.com/jc2jVR):

```
import re

my_string = "The value of the float is 2.5. The int's value is 2.\n"
m = re.search("^(.*?)\.\s", my_string) # Try to find a match
if m:                                  # If there is a match
    print(m.group(1))                  # Show Group 1 value
```

**NOTE** If there can be line breaks in the input, pass `re.S` or `re.DOTALL` flag:

```
m = re.search("^(.*?)\.\s", my_string, re.DOTALL)
```

Comment: Your non-capturing group can also be simply `[ \n]`, right?

Comment: @ImperishableNight Right, I was just in the "multicharacter" wake :(

Answer (score 0):

Besides classic approach explained by Wiktor, also splitting may be interesting solution in this case.

```
>>> my_string
"The value of the float is 2.5. The int's value is 2.\n"
>>> re.split('\. |\.\n', my_string)
['The value of the float is 2.5', "The int's value is 2", '']
```

If you want to include periods at the end of the sentence, you can do something like this:

```
['{}.'.format(sentence) for sentence in re.split('\. |\.\n', my_string) if sentence]
```

To handle multiple empty spaces between the sentences:

```
>>> str2 = "The value of the float is 2.5.   The int's value is 2.\n\n  "
>>> ['{}.'.format(sentence) 
     for sentence in re.split('\. \s*|\.\n\s*', str2) 
     if sentence
     ]
['The value of the float is 2.5.', "The int's value is 2."]
```